# Chrome Ext to open a new tab and populate fields in the newly opened tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, populate

I am trying to build an ext that will Chrome Ext to open a new tab and populate fields in the newly opened tab. So far, I am able to open the new tab but can't get it to populate the fields in the nw tab.

**Popup.html:**

```
<html>
....
/* user selects which url to open*/
<select name="choices" id="choice">
<option value="a"> a</option>
...
</select>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById("choice").addEventListener("change",func)
func(){
switch(choice){
case a:
newurl="https://:.abc.com"
break;
.....
}chrome.tabs.create({url: newurl},populate) // also tried .then( , , ,)
populate(){
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {  \\also tried onUpdated
   chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
     chrome.scripting.executeScript({target : {tabId :getCurrentTab()},files : [ "abc.js" ] })
  });
}
}
```

```
async function getCurrentTab() {
 let queryOptions = { active: true };
let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
}
```

// I figured maybe I should put the onUpdated listener and populate function in the background script, but if I first open the site independently (manually) then run the ext it works, but not if I run it from a different site,

Can anyone provide an example of how to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.